# Is there a way to make SharedPreferences global throughout my whole Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Is there a way to make SharedPreferences global throughout my whole app? Right now I'm using these lines in a lot of places throughout my code to store simple on/off settings for a number of preferences that my users can set. I just want to call them once globally if possible:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
```

Any tips on how to be able to call just these line in all classes would be awesome:

```
editor.putString("examplesetting", "off");
editor.commit();
```

and

```
String checkedSetting = settings.getString("examplesetting", "");
```

Answer (score 19):

Use a singleton class that wraps around the `SharedPreference` settings.. something like this:

```
public class PrefSingleton{
   private static PrefSingleton mInstance;
   private Context mContext;
   //
   private SharedPreferences mMyPreferences;

   private PrefSingleton(){ }

   public static PrefSingleton getInstance(){
       if (mInstance == null) mInstance = new PrefSingleton();
       return mInstance;
   }

   public void Initialize(Context ctxt){
       mContext = ctxt;
       //
       mMyPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
   }
}
```

And create wrapper functions around what your examples represented in the question, for example,

`PrefSingleton.getInstance().writePreference("exampleSetting", "off");`

and the implementation could be something like this:

```
// Within Singleton class

public void writePreference(String key, String value){
     Editor e = mMyPreference.edit();
     e.putString(key, value);
     e.commit();
}
```

From your first activity, activate the singleton class, in this manner, something like this:

```
PrefSingleton.getInstance().Initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Using global static classes can be a bad idea and goes against the practice of programming fundamentals. **BUT** having said that, as nit-picky aside, it will ensure only the one and only object of the class `PrefSingleton` can exist and be accessible regardless of what activities the code is at.

Comment: Do preferences work with the application context? A lot of things don't, so using it is always tricky. Also 'first activity' is a bit undefined, since the app can be started from a broadcast, pending intent (widget, etc.).

Comment: @NikolayElenkov sure, I agree there with you, remember, I put in an generic example that was top of my head...it could be modified to suit one's need. :)

Comment: If you extend Application, couldn't you initialize your singleton in your subclass and avoid the 'first activity' problem?

Answer (score 11):

I would extend `Application` and include the `SharedPreferences.Editor` as a field with a getter.

```
public class APP extends Application {
    private final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    public SharedPreferences.Editor editSharePrefs() {
        return editor;
    }
}
```

Then you can access it from any `Activity` with

```
((APP) getApplication()).editSharePrefs().putString("examplesetting", "off");
((APP) getApplication()).editsharePrefs().commit();
```

Alternatively, you could also throw in the method

```
    public static APP getAPP(Context context) {
        return (APP) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

Although, this would simply change the calls you make to

```
APP.getAPP(this).editSharePrefs().putString("examplesetting", "off");
APP.getAPP(this).editsharePrefs().commit();
```

So it really is a personal preference, which looks cleaner to you.

Comment: While this works, using an application class for this is overkill. Not to mention that you will have to cast it to your concrete class every time. A simple helper class with static methods that take a `Context` parameter (you can just pass `this` when in an activity) is much better. The application doesn't really buy you anything in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this following :

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

        protected boolean setInHistory;
        protected SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    setInHistory = true;
       }


}


public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              System.out.println(setInHistory+" <-- setInhistory");

          }
}
```

Then can access sharedPrefs because it is protected then it's accessible through the package.

```
In the console you have : true <-- setInhistory
```

Comment: This is my favorite solution.

Comment: I think this would only work if you have all your activities extending BaseActivity. What happens if you have Fragments or ViewPagerAdapters that you need to store variables?

Comment: @Simon can you just cast your getActivity? ex, `((MainActivity) getActivity) getSharedPref();` ? how about that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Helper class to get all you want,make the methods static.This is how ADW do.